# Device not getting push notification using ionic push

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

in my app.js of ionic app I have this code

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.controllers','btford.socket-io'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $http,config) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

      var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
    });

    push.register(function(token) {
      push.saveToken(token);  // persist the token in the Ionic Platform
    });

  });

})
```

and I push to ionic push end point, the response I got seems ok, it look like this http://pastebin.com/SjVicY4J

but my device never get the notification. That's so strange. I have no clue what went wrong.